# How To get and convert last character of string into Int in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, string, int

Eg: string is "car1"

I want 1 in integer value in swift 3.
to get last character I am using *string.characters.last*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply convert that last `character` to `String` and then `String` to `Int`.

```
if let last = str.characters.last, let value = Int(String(last)) {
     print(value)
}
```

**Edit:** If you are having a number like cart10,cart11,...cart100... then to get the number after cart try this way.

```
let str = "cart15"
let cartNumber = str.characters.flatMap({Int(String($0))}).reduce(0, {10 * $0 + $1})
print(cartNumber) //15
```

Comment: `let carNumber = str.characters.flatMap({Int(String($0))}).reduce(0, {10 * $0 + $1})`

Answer (score 1):

Use this string extension

```
extension String {

    var toInt:Int?{
        get{
            return Int(self)
        }
    }

    var getOnlyDigits:String?{
        get {
         return self.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()
          }
    }
}
```